# How to insert, display and update an image from folder? not in database in java

Tags: java, sql, database

I'm creating inventory system, and I want each item have an image displayed in Jlabel, I can't figure out how to insert, display and update an image in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

- What you can do here is first you have to come up with a unique fileName for each inventory item then store it somewhere so that you will be able to find the particular image to the item.
- Then write the appropriate code to copy an image from one location to another and delete. Make those as methods so that you can reuse them.

  **insert**
- copy the image to your preferred location using the above method and rename it with the unique image name of the item.

  **update**
- find the image that needs to be updated with the unique file name.
- delete the file that already there
- copy the new image and rename with the previous unique file  name

  **delete**
- find the file by the unique file name and delete it

...
Can help a little bit more if you can add some codes that you wrote